# "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual" statement causing run-time error 1004 in VBA Paste procedure

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am very new to VBA, so I need a lil help trouble shooting this problem.

I am trying to run this code

```
Sub PASTERRR()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ActiveSheet.Range("F15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

But its giving me run-time error 1004. However,

```
Sub PASTERRR()

ActiveSheet.Range("F15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

This code runs fine.

I need the application to stop auto calculation and activate auto calculation after the data has been pasted to speed up the pasting process.

Any other alternate solution will also be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first one, just try and move the paste above `Application...` as a quick test - I wonder if setting calculation undoes the copying you did.

Comment: When you change calculation mode, clipboard is cleared. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/applicationcalculation-state-change-clears/46cd5a0e-bb8c-48ae-b7c6-bb5578296009 so @BruceWayne comment is what you need. As a suggestion, you should copy something only when you are ready to paste it somewhere.